# Centos- how to run yum with the proxy?

Tags: proxy, yum

I come from Iran, where all Oracle products are forbidden to use and download because of US sanctions against us.

I need to install MySQL on my Centos server (that is in Iran) but I can't install MySQL from Oracle's repos.

I want to use proxy. How can I set proxy for yum execution?

Comment: Can you not use mariadb instead ?

Comment: No, i prepare a django project, that works with MySQL. I need mysql

Comment: mariadb is a drop in replacement for mysql and do search engines not work in Iran either ? There's lots of information on the wider internet about using yum with a proxy.

Comment: And mariadb works with mysql-connectors of python?

Comment: On CentOS 7 if you `yum install mysql` you will get mariadb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say which version of CentOS you're using, however it probably doesn't matter. In this particular case you will most likely find it easier just to install mariadb. This is a drop in replacement for mysql that should just work as you expect.

On CentOS 7 mariadb is the default 'mysql' package and

```
yum install mariadb-server mariadb-libs mariadb
```

will get you an environment that acts just like the relevant mysql release.

On CentOS 6 you will need to install the relevant repository you can get the repo file [from here](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=exascale).

Comment: I use Centos 7.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to add to the first answer:
You can setup yum proxy easily:

Edit your /etc/environment file:

```
vi /etc/environment
```

Add the following lines (customized):

```
export http_proxy=http://usr:pwd@server.example:8080
export https_proxy=http://usr:pwd@server.example:8080
export ftp_proxy=http://usr:pwd@server.example:8080
export no_proxy=localhost
```

Source the env file:

```
source /etc/environment
```

Yum should now work over the proxy!